# Is it possible to use PJSIP only for SIP signaling and handle media separately?

Tags: pjsip

Can anybody guide me an API with which I can tell pjsip to use my own
local ports (UDP) to be used for media?
At the time of SDP negotiation, I read that I can get to know about
active local SDP by calling pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_local(), and
active remote SDP by calling pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_remote().

But for an outgoing call, I need to create custom SDP with just
modifying local ports.

Thus, Is there a way to tell PJSIP not to open its ports for media,
and use custom ports created by application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it, for that you should use only pjsip core library and remove other libraries from the pjsip such as pjmedia,codec,nath etc. even i need the samething i.e pjsip only for sip messaging but its really difficult( my exp) still im not able to separate it correctly.

Comment: could you please clarify how to do it? E.g. SDP negotiation is a part of call. But it is implemented in pjmedia lib. Also you cannot remove codecs etc. from pjmedia and use sdp negotiation state machine. Here is a sample: trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/3rd_Party_Media_20
you remove all codecs but have to add custom one. Without it there are lots linking errors