# PJSIP for IM only

Tags: windows, pjsip

We have a problem in that we are already using Dialogic HMP to do SIP call handling. However there is a new requirement to do SIP IM (RFC 3428), and the Dialogic libraries don't handle that.

I have looked at SIP libraries such as PJSIP which are available for Windows. Although these are mostly aimed at client devices rather than servers, I don't see a reason why they couldn't implement a server. However there's a more fundamental problem. It appears that the RTP traffic travels on port 4000, and all signalling is done via listening port 5060. But the Dialogic HMP code already handles INVITE packets, so  I expect it is using 5060. My assumption is that PJSIP therefore won't be able to use that port for SIP IM, and the calling devices won't be configurable to use a different port for IM, they'll expect to use one port for both functions, IM and signalling.

Has anyone else come across this problem? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198377/is-it-possible-to-use-pjsip-only-for-sip-signaling-and-handle-media-separately) question looks like it addresses the problem, but doesn't actually point at a workable solution, only say that it might be possible. Nothing else I've seen seems to offer any hope.